# Парсинг строки регулярных выражений JavaScript

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения, парсер

Приходит текст  /long 786 678 200 
(количество цифр в числах может быть разное)
Он по логике подходит к регулярному выражению  ^(/[l][o][n][g])\s\d\s\d\s\d$
Как присвоить трём разным переменным эти числа?
Спасибо

Comment: let arr = '/long 786 678 200'.split(' '); let a = arr[1], b = arr[2], c = arr[3];

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете использовать *захватывающие подмаски*, `(...)`:

```js
const text = "/long 786 678 200";
[_,first, second, third] = text.match(/^\/long\s+(\d+)\s+(\d+)\s+(\d+)$/);
console.log(first, second, third)
```

чтобы найти 1 и более цифр, после `\d` можно добавить `+`, так называемый "квантификатор", который находит 1 и более повторов модифицируемого шаблона. Соответственно, `\s+` находит 1 и более пробельных символов.